# How to compare color information between two different resolution images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, computer-vision

I want to compare two different resolution images in terms of its color content. Information to be compared should be at a particular position, not the whole image. e.g. Top left corner (exact coordinate is subjected to be varying depending on resolution) of different resolution image. I used SURF for scaling but while it is comparing it uses HSV of the original RGB image. So I can't compare in terms of Color. Please suggest code in MATLAB to do this.

Comment: Please add the code you have used so far in a [mcve]. Editing the question can be done by pressing the "edit" button below the tags on your question.

Answer (score 0):

HSV is a colorspace just like RGB https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV you can actually convert from one to the other using `rgb2hsv` and `hsv2rgb` So if your you specific the color of interest using RGB you can convert it to HSV without any issue.

There are a few advantages to HSV when doing segmentation but the biggest one is that it is lighting invariant. If you are looking for red objects you specify `hue=0.1` and even if an object is partially in a shadow and some of it is well lit you will still be able to identify it. In RGB you would need to specify some range of colors like (1,0,0), (2,0,0), (3,0,0),.... (255,0,0) You can see form this simple example HSV can simplify your color match algorithm